# Adding/updating/removing nested array in algolia

Tags: algolia

In the algolia documentation, they specify that you can manipulate arrays like this:

```
// adding
index.partialUpdateObject({
  myfield: {
    value: 'myvalue',
    _operation: 'Add'
  },
  objectID: 'myID'
})

/removing
index.partialUpdateObject({
  myfield: {
    value: 'myvalue',
    _operation: 'Remove'
  }
})
```

This works well when the array is a string or number. However imagine that I have this document structure, where arrays are actually nested objects:

```
{
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  subjects: [
    {
      itemId: String,
      title: String,
      randomField: String,
      dateAdded: Date
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case the algolia documentation is very unclear. For example, imagine the following scenarios:

- I want to update the `randomField` field of a particular array item. I want to be able to update a nested array item by `itemId`.
- I want to be able to add or remove nested array items. In this case, what do I pass into the "value" field when doing a `partialUpdateObject`.

Is this kind of thing possible in Algolia? What would be your recommendations?

Comment: What I decided to do was fetch the object from Algolia, manipulate the array, and then do an update with the entire array object.

Comment: is the answer still the correct one right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add/update/remove a specific attribute of a nested array using the `partilUpdateObject` function.

You get it right by fetching the object, modifying and updating it after. :)

Comment: is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

It’s still true that you can’t update individual key value with in a nested object